# Is heap fragmentation occuring in this case?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

In a loop with many iterations, at the beginning of the loop I allocate some space, work on it and deallocate it at the end. Something like that:

```
....
while(...){
  list=malloc(N);
  do_some_work_with_list(...)
  free(list)
}
```

Will fragmentation occur here?

PS I already try to post this question, but could not find it afterwards, sorry if duplicated

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please do not post your e-mail in the question.

Comment: @user1523271: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/dyn-mem-alloc.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. If no other allocations occur no fragmentation will occur either because the chunks allocated will be released before allocating the next chunk. However if `do_some_work_with_list` allocates memory that's not freed before returning, fragmentation *may* occur. Also if other threads, library calls etc allocates there *may* be fragmentation.

Comment: `If no other allocations occur no fragmentation will occur either` because the chunks will be consolidated by the allocator.I think this should be mentioned explicitely in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It will totally depend on the memory management technique(eg. allocate Largest free block first / best fit free block first ) of the platform and the current state of allocations in the heap memory.

Since heap is a place for dynamic memory allocations, if a single block large enough for allocation is found then fragmentation will not be caused once you free the memory later.
If a single block is not found due to fragmentation present in heap previously, then most likely fragmentation may increase by this piece of code (also taking into account other threads running on the system may allocate memory simultaneously).